# How do I optimize the following SQL query for performance?

Tags: performance, optimization, sql

How do I optimize the following SQL query for performance?

```
select * from Employee where CNIC = 'some-CNIC-number'
```

Will using alias help making it a little faster?

I am using Microsoft SQL Server.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is better if  you tell us what RDBMS you are using, but...

1 - Don't do `SELECT *`.  Specify which columns you need.  Less data = faster query

2 - For indexing, make sure you have an index on `CNIC`.  You also want a good clustered index on a primary key (preferably something like an ID number)

3 - You put the number in single quotes `' '` which indicates you may have it as a varchar column.  If it will always be NUMERIC, it should be an `int/bigint` data type.  This takes up less space and will be faster to retrieve and index by.

Comment: hmmm, goood. +1 for `Less data = faster query` :)

Comment: to expand on your #1, if the OP can remove the "*" with a small column list (and depending on the database, not all support this) you can create an index and INCLUDE columns that are used in the query.  this is called a covering index, and can speed up the use of a nonclustered index.

Comment: by "INCLUDE" I don't mean to have a multi-column index, but to still have an index only on CNIC, but that data for the other columns is included in the physical index so it prevents a read back on the actual table to get the other data needed, see: [covering index](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Index_%28database%29#Covering_Index)

Answer (score 2):

Create an index on `CNIC`:

```
CREATE INDEX ix_employee_cnic ON employee (cnic)
```

Answer (score 1):

First thing, as I see this column will be used for storing Id card nos, then you can make your coulmn of type `int` rather than `varchar` or `nvarchar` as searching will faster on an integer type as compared to `varchar` or `nvarchar`.

Second, use `with (no lock)`, like

```
select * from Employee with (nolock) where CNIC = 'some-CNIC-number'
```

This is to minimize the chances of a deadlock.